# применить стили media query по отношению ширины родителя

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

Есть ситуация, на сайте при нажатии на кнопку появляется сайдбар `.sidebar` шириной, скажем, `30%`, при этом часть контента `.content` должна стать `70%` вместо `100%`. Так вот, как мне применить стили, которые прописаны в  media query для ширины `70%` ?

По сути мне нужно чтобы содержимое `.content` подстроилось под его ширину так же, как оно это сделало бы при такой же ширине viewport.

Comment: Можно использовать CSS `transform: scale()` для всего блока, топорный вариант, приходилось использовать в некоторых местах, работает. Но если вы пишите про изменение ширины в процентах, значит сайт должен быть резиновым, а в резиновом сайте всё само перестраивается под нужную ширину

Comment: в том то и дело, сайт сам адаптивный, но только адаптируется он под ширину viewport'a, а мне нужно чтобы контент в блоке адаптировался по ширине родителя, то есть примерно так хочу: @media (ширина родителя: 780px)

Answer (score 1):

Создайте класс css `.content70` со всеми необходимыми стилями, и добавляйте его к `.content` при нажатии на кнопку, открывающую сайдбар.